# Nginx Rule to redirect one specific server_name

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an nginx with multiples server_name, and need redirect to https a specific server_name.

With my configuration (below), i got error *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*

My conf:

```
 # /etc/nginx/sites-available/k2cloud_staging

upstream puma_k2cloud_staging {
  server unix:/home/outracoisa/k2cloud/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  server_name contoso.com www.contoso.com contoso.com.br www.contoso.com.br contoso.sapo.pt www.contoso.sapo.pt;
  root /home/outracoisa/k2cloud/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_k2cloud_staging;


  if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
    set $host_without_www $1;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
  }



  rewrite ^/rio/?$ http://contoso.com/rio/pt-BR permanent;
  rewrite ^/lisboa/?$ http://contoso.sapo.pt/lisboa/pt-PT permanent;

  if ($host ~ contoso.com(\.br)) {
    rewrite ^/?$ http://contoso.com/rio/pt-BR permanent;
  }

  if ($host = contoso.sapo.pt) {
    rewrite ^/?$ http://contoso.sapo.pt/lisboa/pt-PT permanent;
  }



  location ~ ^/(rio|lisboa) {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;


    proxy_pass http://puma_k2cloud_staging;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /home/outracoisa/k2cloud/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/outracoisa/k2cloud/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
}

########## Ramos #####
 if ($scheme != "https") {
        set $a x;
}

if ($host = contoso.sapo.pt) {
        set $a "${a}y";
}
if ($a = xy) {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
        break;
        }

################



  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }

  location = /404.html {
    root html;
  }

  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }

  location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
    return 405;
  }
}
```

Anyone can help me to solve it please?

Comment: Use a separate `server` block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do it very complicated. First: [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) :)

As I see you want to do several things:

1. remove the `www` "prefix"
2. `/rio` and `/lisboa`: use a specific host
3. `contoso.com` and `contoso.sapo.pt`: use a specific directory
4. `contoso.sapo.pt`: force `https`

I would do it another way:

1. Use another `server` sections with `server_name www.contoso.com`, `server_name www.contoso.com.br` and `return 301 $scheme://...`.
2. Try `location /rio` and `location /lisboa`! Or maybe better solution is to use `alias` (I think your nginx servers static contents and the `/rio/pt-BR` is a directory on your server).
3. Use `server` blocks!
4. Again in `server` block! `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

I think it would be easier maintain and debug if you create small blocks not only big one with many `if` and `rewrite`.

Comment: It's good ideia :)

If is evil, but in location, but evil rsrsrs, i'll try it and post the fix here.

Thks you!!